# How to encode Unicode to ASCII with HTML entities

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I need to encode a unicode UTF-8 string into ASCII with HTML entities in Python.

To be clear:

```
source = u"Hello…"
wanted = "Hello&hellip;"
```

This is not the solution:

```
as_ascii = source.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
```

because `as_ascii` will be set to `Hello&#8230;` - ie, using the XML character reference, not the HTML one.

Is there a Python module/function/dictionary-of-entities that can either:

1. Decode unicode into ASCII with HTML character references.
2. Replace an ASCII string that has XML character references with HTML character references (as appropriate).

Comment: For the dictionary-of-entities, would `htmlentitydefs.codepoint2name` help with approach 2?  `htmlentitydefs.codepoint2name[8230] == "hellip"`.

Comment: yes! thanks.  i can work with htmlentitydefs!

Comment: i had to pull out a handful of elements from the htmlentitydefs package, but I came up with this -- https://gist.github.com/jvanasco/7030697

Comment: Numeric character references are just as valid in HTML as they are in XML, and you will presumably need them for all the characters that don't have HTML-specific entities.

Comment: Yes, I know they are equivalent when rendering. I specifically want the HTML entities.

Answer (score 2):

Example procedure  (file `decode_to_entity.py`):

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import htmlentitydefs as entity

def decode_to_entity(s):
        t = ""
        for i in s:
                if ord(i) in entity.codepoint2name:
                        name = entity.codepoint2name.get(ord(i))
                        t += "&" + name + ";"
                else:
                        t += i
        return t



print(decode_to_entity(u"Hello…"))
```

And example execution:

```
$ python decode_to_entity.py
Hello&hellip;
```

Comment: Wow. That worked on my unicode string, but I don't understand WHY it worked. I have japanese text and 'xmlcharrefreplace' also works for web-display, but worried that input from web won't be stored as proper utf8. How do I reverse this process for web output text to store in a database as UTF8?

Comment: Because `ord` return integer value of char (can be bigger than 255). Look at this: `a=u'Ś'` this is `u'\u015a'` and `15a` in hex is 346 in decimal format (human readable) (and `ord(a)` will return `346`). You can read more here: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code